# Как поставить степень в C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Как можно поставить степень в тексте C#? Имеется ввиду надстрочный знак в текстовом элементе на платформе ASP

Comment: Возведение в степень числа? x ^ k → Math.Pow(x, k)

Comment: Если имеется ввиду, что нужно проставить надстрочный знак в текстовом элементе, то укажите какую платформу Вы используете для интерфейса (Windows Forms, WPF, ASP или др.). Приведите пример обычного текста и ожидаемого результата

Comment: да, имеется ввиду надстрочный знак в текстовом элементе на платформе ASP. пример даже сюда не вводится. например: Demand3. 3-ка должна стоять вверху как степень числа.

Comment: Т.е. надстрочный знак в веб-странице? Типа: ¹²³?

Comment: а в файле .cs как?

Comment: @AidanaSyzdykova, отредактируйте вопрос и напишите конкретнее что вы делаете, пока ничего не понятно. И да, если вам подойдет метод с юникод-символами, то в cs их тоже можно использовать, еще как вариант записать их по коду: `\x2086`

Answer (score 5):

Воспользуйтесь специальным тегом, делающим текст надстрочным: <sup>как здесь</sup>

Это получено с помощью кода: `<sup>как здесь</sup>`

Также, в таблице символов юникода есть некоторые готовые надстрочные знаки, например, для распространенных степеней - квадрат², куб³

[Надстрочные и подстрочные знаки в таблице символов Юникода](https://unicode-table.com/ru/#superscripts-and-subscripts)

---

В cs-файлах вы также можете использовать юникод: `string s = "3⁵"`, ну и любой символ можно представить в виде его кода: `string s = "3\x2075"`, результат в обоих случаях будет аналогичный: 3⁵